# Import/export report from one SAP system to other?

Tags: abap

Is there a way to port a report with its objects like: STATUS GUI, table from one system to another in SAP software without copy paste everything?

Comment: yes, but the abapgit copy all package. I would to copy only some object of the package.

Comment: ABAPGit allows you to only pull specific objects from the package when you import a zip file.

Comment: thanks, i used it, with two local package thanks a lot. It is going.

Answer (score 0):

Obtaining a table report requires you to run a transaction where you input some data prior to obtaining the report, like date interval, material codes and so on.

Given the fact that obtaining a table report requires you to run a transaction where you input some data prior to obtaining the report, I don't understand how to port a table - which is a result - from one SAP system to another, but you can input the same data programmatically into transaction prior to obtaining a table, in both SAP systems.

It can be done by recording a VBS script from one SAP system's macro recorder, then editing the VBS file in order to meet you requirements for both systems.